# On Visual Studio 2013 sp 4: Add New Items screen, I Cant Find All The items related to Test Template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I had installed **Visual Studio Ultimate Edition 2013 Service Pack 4 with Group License Key**.  I did this for my job .  When I go to add new items to the project on the New items menu.  Under the installed Visual C#.  I see Test but i'm missing Basic Unit Test, Load Test, Coded UI Test Map, Web Porformance test.  I only see these three items Items when I click on new project. I see Coded UI Test Project, Unit Test Project, and Web Performance Load test.

Why don't I see those other items associated with test like basic unit test, coded UI test, load test, unit test, web performance test, coded UI test map.

Is my license does not allow me to see this or is this due to installation or something else.  I thought 2013 ultimate would have all this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you have to open and create a coded U.I project to be given those options any other type of project that you start that isn't a coded U.I project then you are only given Unit test, coded UI, and load test projects as options.